# Redirect in react-router-dom change url but not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect my app from "/" to "/login" by using Redirect.

There is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Login'

@withRouter
export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

On first render url changind but {Login} component doesn't render.

BUT when I reloading the page, {Login} component rendering, and all work correctly.

(for more info) This component nested in Router with history prop.

Can anyone please help me find where is trouble?

EDITED: delete 'push' from Redirect, still doesn't work

Comment: delete `push` from `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />`.

Comment: deleted, but still doesn't work

Comment: Do make a minimally reproducible code. Otherwise, no one can actually see what's happening and can only guess. Try https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: did you try to write `<Route path="/login"> <Login /> </Route>` and see if it works ?

Comment: it should already work. I guess it could have something to do with your `wthRouter` or something else. You can see this simple working [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xnnisp?file=src%2FApp.js) as reference

Comment: https://github.com/13shutt/tg-one/blob/master/client/src/view/Routes.js#L25
here is my repo

Comment: it works in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-hill-3nfqm?file=/src/view/Routes.js) but doesn't work in me app))
perhaps I did something wrong